# Vue js получение данных перед загрузкой страницы

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет! Изучаю vue, из документации не совсем понимаю, как можно получить данные от серверной часть, перед загрузкой страницы.

Как лучше использовать методы? Есть какие-либо ХОРОШИЕ примеры, с использованием полученных данных затем в computed свойствах, чтобы работало без ошибок?

Пример: получить данные от серв части, заранее по этим данными сделать парочку computde свойств и в шаблоне их отобразить

Аналогия asyncData в nuxt.js

Comment: Никак, ибо вебприложение на Vue это скрипт страницы, а скрипты страниц выполняются одновременно с загрузкой документа (или после... но уж никак не **до**). Если же ты хотел спросить про инициализацию состояния вебприложения, то рекомендую начать с чтения оф. документации Vue, повторно (хотя бы до главы, посвященной жизненному циклу компонента... ну и ту что про реактивность, тоже желательно прочесть). Хорошие примеры - в документации Vue есть.

Comment: Т.е. никак нельзя загрузить данные с сервера до загрузки страницы? Про жизненные циклы читал, разумеется)

Comment: До загрузки страницы (при загрузке документа) - можно. И в доках расписано, где и как это следует делать... поэтому не вижу смысла копипастить сюда, и имхо достаточно указания на нужный раздел. А перед загрузкой (до того как документ начнет загружаться) - выполнять скрипты нельзя. Можно "сказать" браузеру чтобы он файлы скриптов заранее скачал, но выполнение скриптов начнется только при загрузке документа.

Comment: Т.е. при загрузке документа зайдет только хук - created?

Comment: И created, и последующие. Можно ли в `created` инициализировать приложение начальным состоянием - да, конечно можно. Только надо понимать две вещи, о которых написано выше: 1. Скрипты страницы выполняются в процессе подготовки документа страницы, или же после нее (других вариантов нет); 2. На момент начала выполнения кода вебприложения (скриптов страницы), часть документа уже загружена, и документ временно "завис"... продлевать это зависание ожиданием ответа на AJAX запрос - это очень, очень дурная идея. Вместо этого, стоит сразу же обеспечить юзеру интерактивность.

Comment: Да, я тоже так делаю, через created, либо mounted. Как раз с некоторыми моментами могут быть проблемы, например получаем курсы (courses), в них есть какой-нибудь объект, и у объекта свойство. То при обращении в template к свойству объекта будет ошибка! Пример: courses.lessons.id (поскольку данные еще не получены). Как можно это избежать? Не рендерить блок?

Comment: _«при обращении в template к свойству объекта будет ошибка! Пример: courses.lessons.id (поскольку данные еще не получены).»_ - такие ошибки уже относятся не к готовности данных, это больше следствие неправильной работы с Vue (ее реализацией реактивности). Пожалуйста, обрати внимание на совет более внимательно изучить доки Vue, в них про это написано. Более грамотным решением, в плане избежания ошибок, было бы заранее объявить все реактивные свойства. Но ты конечно прав в том, что можно просто не рендерить компонент, используя `v-if` - тогда ошибки не будет (это подходит для показа заглушки).

Comment: Да, именно не готовность данных я и имел ввиду. Окей, спасибо! А про более грамотный способ обработки, можешь подсказать (кинуть ссылку), что это за метод такой?)

Comment: Так это обычный подход: просто объявление в объектах внутри `data` компонента (или внутри `state` vuex) всех свойств, которые могут быть считаны при первом же рендеринге разметки. Вот смотри, если мы представим классический пример ToDo-приложения (с серверным состоянием), то вместо `items: null` в `data` и `this.items = await fetch(...)` в `created`, мы можем сразу объявить `items: [{ title: '', checked: false, ... }]` и не блокировать/прятать UI пока ToDo'шки юзера скачиваются с сервера... так и ошибок рендеринга нет, и юзер может вводить новые данные (когда придет ответ, выполним их слияние)

Comment: А. Про это читал.) Я просто думал есть совсем другой подход. Просто если вложенность большая, или много данных, это будет не очень, как считаешь?

Comment: Другие подходы конечно есть, включая и те что касаются той самой предзагрузки данных до запроса документа (из воркера, серверпушем сгенеренных бэкэндом файлов, и т.д.) - но они, имхо, все весьма продвинутые в плане реализации и концепций... Поэтому, перед тем, как в такие другие сложные подходы залезать, разумнее будет притвориться что их нет, и получше изучить Vue (как минимум - до того уровня, когда ошибки рендеринга и вопросы построения бизнеслогики компонентов перестанут смущать). Я вот не смогу тут дать ответ с объяснением таких комплексных вещей "на пальцах". Может кто-то другой сможет))

Comment: _«если вложенность большая, или много данных, это будет не очень»_ - хз, это скорее вопрос личного восприятия... для меня (пришедшего из компилируемых языков), практика объявления переменных и структур заранее, выглядит вполне нормальной. Динамичность объектов в JS безусловно мощный инструмент, но думаю что разработчику инструменты стоит использовать, а не самому быть используемым ими. Еще есть такое мнение: большая вложенность == чрезмерная связность в данных == плохие архитектурные решения (можно напихивать все в один объект, а можно декомпозировать его на несколько более простых и удобных).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я понял логику.) Да, декомпозировать однозначно нужно, но не всегда это получается со стороны серверной части, к сожалению